# Capture word after first dot and before second dot

Tags: javascript, regex

i have some strings like:

```
test.router.router1.ping 
test.router.hp.upload
demo.firewall.router.ping
```

I'm trying to write a regex that makes the first two string pass, but not the third one. The rule is that if the string contains the word "router" after the first dot and before the second dot it's ok.

i tried with

```
[\.router\.]
```

but it match every .router. in my string, so also the third one pass.

how can i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^.]*\.router\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ0UDe/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E.%5D*%5C.router%5C.):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`
- `\.router\.` - a `.router.` substring.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = [ 'test.router.router1.ping', 'test.router.hp.upload', 'demo.firewall.router.ping']
var rx = /^[^.]*\.router\./;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  console.log(strs[i], '=>', rx.test(strs[i]))
}
```

Comment: what if i want that the regex outputs me only the word "router"?

Comment: @FrancescoFattori Do you mean you want to get `router` if a string matches the pattern? Just use `if (rx.test(str))  { return "router"; }`. Note that `router` is a hardcoded pattern part, you do not have to get it from the match.

Comment: @FrancescoFattori `var rx = /^[^.]*\.(router)\./;` => `var m = str.match(rx); if (m) { return m[1]; }` is also a possible way, but it makes sense for unknown, non-hardcoded patterns.

Comment: for seconds faster than me +1

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the following regex

```
^[A-Za-z]*\.router\.
```

`^` matches the beginning of the word, `[A-Za-z]*` is supposed to match everything that is allowed between dots.

I tried the regex here https://regex101.com/r/okTpdr/1

You can also remove the global modifier so it only matches the first instance of the regex

Answer (score 0):

```js
 //Here's you can capture the word before and after dot
const str = 'device.string';
const before = str.match(/[^.]*/)[0];    
const after =  str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) 

console.log("before", before);

console.log("after", after);
```